# Pure virtual and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, pure-virtual

Possibly I just missed something from the documentation (or just can't do a proper Google serach), but I have issues with a `shared_ptr` and pure virtual functions.

So a short example which works:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int stuff() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int stuff() {return 6;}
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container() : m_x( 0 ) {}
    Container(Base* x) : m_x(x) {} 

private:
    Base* m_x;
};
```

and since I'd like to use the new fancy `std::shared_ptr` I modify the `Container` to be:

```
class Container
{
public:
    Container() : m_x( std::make_shared<Base>() ) {}
    Container(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& x) : m_x(x) {} 

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> m_x;
};
```

Obviously, this does not work, clang and other compilers complain, that: `error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'Base'` in the `Container() : m_x( std::make_shared<Base>() ) {}` line.

So, the question: How to make this work with `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: The default constructor initializer is incorrect, and simply should not be there. `std::shared_ptr<>` like  any pointer, can contain *nullptr*, and will do so with default construction.

Comment: where is virtual destructor for base?

Comment: @spin_eight Good point, but not required for `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Problem is here:

```
Container() : m_x( std::make_shared<Base>() ) {}
```

You cannot create an object of Base. What you want is an empty `shared_ptr`. So do this.

```
Container() : m_x( std::shared_ptr<Base>() ) {}
```

or do this.

```
Container() : m_x() {}
```

Which is equal.

Comment: Yeah ... obviously I need a coffee :) Thanks!

Comment: or simply `Container() {}`

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_shared<Base>()` is equivalent to `new Base()`. What you want is either completely omit `m_x` initialization(which will be initialized empty by default constructor) or do it explicitly:

```
Container() : m_x(nullptr) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a templated constructor for directly constructing the object.
So, you cannot have a default constructor unless

- B gets non-abstract,
- you decide for one concrete favored derived class or
- you accept 0-initialising `m_x`.